# Representation Formula in $W_0^{1,2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I don't understand why if $u\in W_0^{1,2}$ I can represent $u$ as
$$u(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{B_1(0)}\Delta u(y)\log|x-y|dy$$

Comment: This "question" is not a question.

Comment: Thank you Umberto

Comment: @mathmagic I'll follow this question, (I will repeat some Sobelev-spaces until tomorrow, and when I'm done with my work I can try again to answer) It's a interesting topic; this one.  //Have a continuing pleasant day!